# Objective C - Salt / MD5 hash?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, md5

I am creating an app that will require authentication which I have already gotten working with a login View in XCode.  the method I am using currently builds the URL that i submit to my server but it is submitting the login and password in plain test as appended to the url as follows:

http://myurl.com/auth.php?email=email@domain.com&password=mypassword

I did receive some vague advice that they used a "salt and hash 40 character token" but have not been able to see how/where this was done.  I can perform some actions on the server side to manipulate data but need to be able to de-salt / de-hash anything i do in xcode ..

Is there a way to have Objective C provide an MD5 hash of the provided password so that the text in the URL request is already encrypted before I submit the url request? I can validate in server side PHP that the MD5 hash provided matches the database's MD5 hash so that would be perfect if it is possible.

If not then I need to create a method for this salt/hash I can create in Objective C that has to be something I can unravel in PHP to compare to my database.

Thanks in advance.

Silver Tiger

**UPDATE: 1-14-2012**

Unfortunately the server and SSL options are not under my control though i can make recommendations. I will have to further research SHA1 and/or base64 so that I can create the hash in the app and recreate/compare it on the server. Any pointers to a decent read would be appreciated until I can get SSL.

Comment: If you control the server you can use HTTPS instead of HTTP and encrypt the entire connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to "be able to de-salt / de-hash anything i do in xcode".
This is not how cryptography works.

Just compare the hash of the text entered with the hash of the expected text.

The server will probably give you the hashed version of login+password
Just compute the hash of the entered login+password on your side in Xcode too and compare the two results.

`if ([response_of_server_containing_sha1_of_password equalsToString:[self sha1OfString:password_string_entered_by_user]]) ...`

Or more probably this comparison is done server-side, meaning you probably will send the `sha1(password_entered_by_user)` to the server and they will compare it with the SHA1 of the password they have stored in their database.

Anyway, no need to have a bidirectonal cryptography here and no need to decipher ("decrypt"/"de-hash") anything.

You obviously need to get more info from the guys implementing the server side of the authentication server, if they don't give you all the needed information, as which hash (md5? sha1?) they expect you to send, etc.

*(Note anyway, doing authentication in such ways won't protect the site from security breaches like MITM or replay attacks. If you need better security, consider using SSL / HTTPS)*

Comment: the server is actually just a php page i have written and a mysql database holding the MD5 hash of the password :)... guess i'll have to read up some more.

Comment: Then the typical solution is simple: make your iPhone app send the MD5 of the password typed by the user, then on the server side, compare the received MD5 with the one stored in your mysql database, and finally make your server respond with OK or KO to tell your iPhone app if the pwd is correct.

Comment: Note anyway that this is a very simple solution that is not really secure. First, nowadays prefer using SHA1 instead of MD5. And anyway, this procedure I described won't protect you very strongly, at least against MITM attacks for example. So if you don't really need strong protection but just basic one it may be sufficient, but if you need stronger protection consider using HTTPS at least, and/or other methods (certificates, OAuth, …). This is more complicated to understand and implement so of course go this way only if you need some real protection.

Comment: Unfortunately the server and SSL options are not under my control though i can make recommendations.  I will have to further research SHA1 and/or base64 so that I can create the hash in the app and recreate/compare it on the server. Any pointers to a decent read would be appreciated until I can get SSL.

Comment: Base64 is not a cryptographic hash. It is a content transfert encoding. It doesn't crypt anything (and is not meant to). Note the same aim at all than MD5 or SHA1 hash functions (which in turn only compute the hash (non-inversible determinist surjective function) of a string and has a different aim than private&public key pairs used in algorithm like RSA/PKCS1 or such used in SSL)

Comment: heh.. wordy, but accepted :) ... I'll research SHA1 and see if i can get my app and server to figure out the comparison. much apprecaited

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OpenSSL [C functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/md5.3ssl.html).  You'll then need to convert the output into something that can be encoded in a URL.  It's common to use base64 although you could just turn the output into hex.

NB if you have control over both ends of the connection, be aware that MD5 is no longer considered cryptographically secure.  You might want to consider one of the SHA family of hashes instead.

Comment: Just to back this up: it's a really bad idea to send a hashed password over HTTP, much much worse than using SSL/HTTPS. This is because it's fairly trivial for someone with enough technical knowledge to break your app apart and figure out what you're salting with.